# Strange behavior of `unset` for local variables

Tags: bash, function, variables, local-variables, unset

I can't explain the following behavior of `unset`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_unset() { unset "$@"; }

fn1() { local var;    unset var; var=1; }
fn2() { local var; my_unset var; var=2; }

var=0

fn1; echo "$var"
fn2; echo "$var"
```

```
0
2
```

<sup>**edit:** I would expect the result to be `1` `2`</sup>

It behaves that way on `bash 3/4/5`, is it a bug?

---

###### update

Here's an other example that shows that using `my_unset` doesn't make the variable global; it only removes the local variable from the current context:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_unset() { unset "$@"; }

fn1() { local var; my_unset var; var=1; }
fn2() { local var; fn1; echo "[fn2] var=$var"; }

var=0
fn2
echo "[global] var=$var"
```

```
[fn2] var=1
[global] var=0
```

Comment: Doing the unset in another function is somehow removing the localness of the variable.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but it doesn't make it a global variable necessarily; I'll add an other example to the question.

Comment: Have you searched the bash bug list?

Comment: @Barmar Not yet; that would be a very long standing bug

Comment: I wonder if the output should be `1 2`. `local` "creates a variable", then `unset` "removes the variable", so `var=1` should refer to var at global scope. `localvar_unset` changes the behavior to `0 0`. There is also this in docs `If the unset acts on a variable at a previous scope, any instance of a variable with that name that had been shadowed will become visible`,  maybe this is expected behavior, if you unset in the current scope, it remains local.

Comment: @KamilCuk `localvar_unset` was added in bash 5. Apparently older versions act as if it's set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Chet's answer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00214.html) back in year 2012:

> Back a number of years ago (16, to be exact), bash behaved like you expect.  Between bash-1.14 and bash-2.0, I changed it in response to a number of bug reports that complained that a variable declared local in a function wasn't local when assigned a value in the function after being unset. Bash keeps a
> placeholder in the function's variable context so subsequent references to
> that unset variable don't traverse back through the call chain.  This
> placeholder affects functions called by the function unsetting the local
> variable in the way you would expect dynamic scoping to work.
>
> This only affects the current function, though: an unset issued from
> farther down the call chain, as you discovered, will unset the local
> variable without creating a placeholder.

Comment: see how the cool `upvar()/upvars()` are using this _feature_: https://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference

Comment: Nice find! I didn't remember that at all. :)